# Excel - mutliline text in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I got multiline text in a  table cell.
after setting the width and hieght in order to show the first row only 
i'd like the full content multiline expand when clicking on the cell.
cell is text wrapped.

is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Maybe with macros but this functionality would either have to happen on specific cells, or every cell. The concept would be, onclick, take a note of width and height of current cell, and then resize to a given size or auto size. Then when you leave, reset the values back.

Answer (score 0):

Open macro editor, on the left tree under Microsoft Excel Objects double click the *Sheet* where you want this behavior, then in the right side paste this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    cell_width = Target.Width
    cell_height = Target.Height
    Target.Rows.AutoFit
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) 'time expanded
    Target.RowHeight = cell_height
End Sub
```

Now, whenever someone double click on a cell, it will expand and after 5 seconds will be back to its original size.

It will disable editing by double click and writing on the cell, but not editing on the formula field. If it is necessary to edit on the cell simply change `Cancel=True` to `Cancel=False`

Comment: This will disable the default double click function (edit contents) right?

Comment: It will disable editing by double click and writing on the cell, but not editing on the formula field. If it is necessary to edit on the cell simply change `Cancel=True`to `Cancel=False`

Comment: You should add that note to the answer so others don't get confused. One could also add an `intersect` to restrict it to the table.